# Request to MVC controller method creates custom culture in Globalization folder and returns 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore8, windows-server-2016, iis-10

We have deployed our application on Windows Server 2016 for the first time and find an unusual problem for one particular asp.net mvc controller action. The route is defined as:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "AdsService",
            "ads-service/{Action}",
            new { controller = "AdsService" },
            namespaces: new[] { "XXXX.XXXX.Areas.Ads.Controllers" }
            );
```

When the request is made to a URL like this:

https://hostname/ads-service/methodname?param1=value1

The server generates an ads-service.nlp file in the C:\Windows\Globalization folder.

The request then returns a 404.

Looking at the IIS logs and the Failed Request Tracing logs it seems like the controller name is being stripped from the URL at some point during request processing. The IIS logs record the request as:

https://hostname/methodname?param1=value1

The request tracing indicates the URL was received including the controller name (ads-service) but shows the URL processed as being without the controller name.

I can surmise that something in the request pipeline is mistaking the "ads-" as a region/language identifier. If I remove the hyphen, the IIS log and request tracing record the full URL including the modified controller name "adsservice". The same happens if I make it "adsZZZZ-service". Suggesting something is matching on a very specific pattern.

The question is, what would be doing this? I have checked all the language settings and everything is configured as English or otherwise the same as other functional (non-2016) servers.

Sitecore is also in the mix but it's logs shed no light on the problem.

Comment: Are other working controller inside Areas? I suspect with Areas.

Comment: @AkashKC Yes, about a dozen other areas, all functioning correctly. Other routes have hyphens in the name, but none with three characters followed by a hyphen.